# Permission denied when running scheduling Vertex Pipelines

Tags: google-cloud-functions, vertex, google-cloud-scheduler

I wish to schedule a Vertex Pipelines and deploy it from my local machine for now.
I have defined my pipeline which runs well I deploy it using: `create_run_from_job_spec`, on AIPlatformClient running it once.
When trying to schedule it with `create_schedule_from_job_spec`, I do have a Cloud Scheduler object well created, with a http endpoint to a Cloud Function. But when the scheduler runs, it fails because of Permission denied error. I used several service accounts with owner permissions on the project.
Do you know what could have gone wrong?

Since AIPlatformClient from Kubeflow pipelines raises deprecation warning, I also want to use PipelineJob from google.cloud.aiplatform but I cant see any direct way to schedule the pipeline execution.

Comment: The documentation recommends creating "a service account to run your pipelines and then grant this account granular permissions to the Google Cloud resources that are needed to run your pipeline". Did you try to [configure granular permissions](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/configure-project#service-account) for your service account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spent about 3 hours banging my head on this too.  In my case, what seemed to fix it was either:

- disabling and re-enabling cloud scheduler api.  Why did I do this? There is supposed to be a service account called service-[project-number]@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com.  If it is missing then re-enabling API might fix it
- for older projects there is an additional step: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#add

Simpler explanations include not doing some of the following steps

- creating a service account for scheduler job.  Grant cloud function invoker during creation
- use this service account (see create_schedule_from_job_spec below)
- find the (sneaky) cloud function that was created for you it will be called something like 'templated_http_request-v1' and add your service account as a cloud function invoker

```
response = client.create_schedule_from_job_spec(
job_spec_path=pipeline_spec,
schedule="*/15 * * * *",
time_zone="Europe/London", 
parameter_values={},
cloud_scheduler_service_account="<your-service-account>@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
)
```

If you are still stuck, it is also useful to run `gcloud scheduler jobs describe <pipeline-name>` as it really helps to understand what scheduler is doing.  You'll see cloudfunction url, POST payload which is some base64 encoded and contains pipeline yaml and you'll see that it is using OIDC/service account for security.  Also useful is to view the code of the 'templated_http_request-v1' cloud function (sneakily created!).  I was able to invoke the cloudfunction from POSTMAN using the payload obtained from scheduler job.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the sharing ! I have also spent quite some time on it and after many trials I managed to make it work. However I tested so many things that I dont really know in the end what made it work, these permissions issues are not that clear sometimes on GCP.